# Altering an Apache CustomURL / Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I had the following rewriting set up in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ profile.php?customURL=$1 [NC,L]
```

It worked great for a-z A-Z 0-9, but now I need to add support for hyphens.

So I changed it to:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$ profile.php?customURL=$1 [NC,L]
```

But now PHP can't see the contents of `$_GET["customURL"]` (i.e. it's empty). What have I done wrong?

Comment: you forgot storing the value using `()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ profile.php?customURL=$1 [NC,L]
```

and it works like a charm.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. Silly me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?$ profile.php?customURL=$1 [NC,L]
```

Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you skipped the parantheses to group for $1:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+$ profile.php?customURL=$1 [NC,L]
```